# Force Click to preview items in Safari doesn't work

Tags: safari, trackpad, look-up, haptic-feedback

I tried to change to tap with three finger and it works on all Safari, Mail, Note,...

When I changed to Force Click to Lookup data and defectors, it doesn't work on Safari, but every other apps go well.

What should I do to fix this?

I'm using macOS 10.12.4, MacBook Pro 15inch Late 2015

Answer (score 1):

Well I restarted my Mac and everything works perfectly...